# Using LSTM's on Multivariate Input AND Multivariate Output

Tags: python, keras, time-series, predictive-modeling, lstm

I have a very small dataset, only about 40 rows, that has historical usage data for a few categories (roughly 20). I strongly suspect that these categories are dependent in a partial-zero-sum-game fashion: if the usage of one category goes up, I'm expecting that of another to go down. My goal is to predict the next row *of all categories*.

I've looked at [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37212/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-using-lstm), but it's not predicting multiple variables. I also looked at [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/multivariate-multistep-forecasting-with-lstm), but it's still univariate output (albeit multiple time steps) and multivariate input. So far, I've been basing my approach on the typical LSTM post [here at machinelearningmastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/), but it's also a single-output-variable example, and a number of the functions used, such as `scaler.inverse_transform` don't appear to broadcast very well. I'm even having difficulties trying to scale back my full example to match his!

Any tips for scaling LSTM's up to multivariate output? Can the keras LSTM do this natively? If so, how would the code change?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply change the number of units at the last layer if you want to predict multiple outputs (or just said differently, one output with multiple features). For example from the link you shared, you can change the units of the Dense layer:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
```

The above model would now predict the next step of an output with 2 "features". 
Note that you output should be of shape num_samplesx2 now.

Comment: You wrote, "The above model would not predict..." Did you mean "The above model would now predict..."?

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks! I wouldn't have bothered, but it did change the meaning of the sentence a fair bit. I'll try it out!

Comment: Yes, it certainly does :).

Comment: I'm getting an error in the next line: `history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=100, batch_size=72, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)`. The error is: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (17,) but got array with shape (1,)`. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your code? Either here or in stackoverflow. We need to take a look at input and ouput shapes to debug this.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code as a whole is likely proprietary. Here is the result of `model.summary()`:

Comment: Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   

    lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 50)                16800     

    dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 17)                867       

    Total params: 17,667
    Trainable params: 17,667
    Non-trainable params: 0

Comment: Just from the error message, seems like you have Dense(17) as the output layer, but you train_y is of shape (num_samples, 1). If you have multivariate output, I would expect train_y to be of shape (num_samples, 17).  Same story with test_y.

Comment: And here is the result of printing up the shape of all the input variables:
train_X shape: (24, 1, 33)
train_y shape: (24,)
test_X shape: (13, 1, 33)
test_y shape: (13,)

Comment: train_x should be of shape (num_samples, num_observations, num_x_features). train_y should be of shape (num_samples, num_y_features). I do not see this pattern with you data shape. Looks like train_y is not multivariate, it's just a scaler.

Comment: What is the difference between num_samples and num_observations?

Comment: num_samples is like how many samples you have for training. num_observations is how long is each sample, or how many time steps you have in each sample.

Comment: I'm beginning to see what my problem is: I have 17 columns of historical data. The predictive goal is, for each of those same 17 columns, to predict the next value. In a situation like that, how should I define `train_y` and `test_y`?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, by the way! You're awesome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88512/discussion-between-adrian-keister-and-sata).